# Win IoT & RPI3: DEP6701 Deploy Error

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

First time using Windows IoT.

> Error: (Deploying ARM C# UWA(
> 1>DEP6701: Bootstrapping failed with an unexpected error: 'DEP6960 : Source doesn't exist: C:....\12.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\corelr.dll
>
> OS VERSION: 10.0.14393.0

Comment: What's your Visual Studio version?